# Table structure for storing communities in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

I have a list of communities. Each community has a list of members. Currently I am storing each community in a row with the member names separated by a comma. This is good for smaller immutable communities. But as the communities are growing big, let us say with 75,000 members, loading of communities is becoming slower. Also partial loading of a community (let us say random 10 members) is also not very elegant. What would be the best table structure for the communities table in this scenario? Usage of multiple tables is also not an issue if there is a reason for doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use three tables

```
`community`

| id | name | other_column_1 | other_column_2 ...

`user`

| id | name | other_column_1 | other_column_2 ...

`community_user`

| id (autoincrement) | community_id | user_id |
```

Then to get user info for all users in a community you do something like this

```
SELECT cu.id AS entry_id, u.id, u.name FROM `community_user` AS cu
    LEFT JOIN `user` AS u 
    ON cu.user_id = u.id 
WHERE cu.community_id = <comminuty id>
```